# Doctrine subqueries in SELECT

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

```
SELECT u FROM AcmeBundle:Users u
```

The statement above returns all records from the users table. What if I want to add something else, like:

```
SELECT u, (
   SELECT s.name
   FROM AcmeBundle:Shop s
   ) AS shop_name
FROM AcmeBundle:Users u
```

Executing the second query throws an error that userId for array with keys "u, shop_name" does not exist. What's wrong?

Comment: That's not a valid Doctrine query. It would be helpful, if you'd tell what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That's valid DQL query in symfony 2, from what I know. I'm simply trying to redurn everything from the users table, and one column from the shop table - just like in the second query.

Comment: Normally it's doesn't make sense to just get the data from one field. Doctrine is primary designed to return a collection of entities. You can return scalar values, but not a mixture of scalars and entities. In any case you'll need to join the two entities. What is the relation between the two tables?

Comment: One to many. I actually need this to paginate results (knplabs bundle). It only works when I pass the whole objects to the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you probably want something like

```
SELECT u, s FROM AcmeBundle:Users u JOIN u.shop s
```

where `shop` is the name of the property in the `User` entity that refers to the `Shop` entity.

You then can access the name of the shop when you have a `User` entity with

```
$user->getShop()->getName()
```